# GParted -- expand to the left

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I have empty space to the right of my Windows partition, but it is to the left of my GRUB and Ubuntu partitions. How can I add this space to my Ubuntu partition?

It looks like in the screenshot:

[image: GParted screenshot]

I think that the bios_grub partition is from a previous, non-EFI attempt to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Are Ubuntu partition and empty space contiguous? It would be great if you can post screenshot of your GParted.

Comment: were it not for the grub partition (I never used that) this question would have been a duplicate (just like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1100343/47206)). I suggest from a live session deleting the grub partition, then extending (move/resize) to the left as in the linked answers, then still in the live session using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to reinstall grub (I don't think one really needs a separate partition for that, just install it in sda with boot flag on sda8).

Comment: @cipricus The bios_grub partition is necessary for the setup with legacy boot (not UEFI) and GPT.

Comment: @Melebius `sda2` is mounted on `/boot/efi`. That indicates that Ubuntu is installed in UEFI-mode, so the `bios_grub`- partition wouldn't be needed, maybe it's a left-over from an install in the wrong boot-mode.

Comment: @Melebius - I don't know much about grub partitions, never used one, so I do not know how easy/safe is to (1) move/rezise or (2) delete/recreate one, but (1) or (2) is necessary anyway. On the other hand, as said in a comment, that partition might still not be needed.

Comment: Yes, I think that the bios grub partition is from a previous, non-EFI attempt to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to clarify -- if I delete the grub partition from a live flash drive session, I can then expand my ubuntu partition to the left, into the unallocated space?

Comment: In case the grub partition is not needed, your question stands as a duplicate of the one(s) linked to the one linked in my comment. Although closed, even that one has answers. **Be sure that you know how to backup data** - or be sure you don't care  or love deadly risks - , be sure you know how to use gparted (or similar software), live session usb etc

Comment: IMHO the safest option is to [create a new partition and mount it](https://askubuntu.com/a/862195/250300) where it’s meaningful in your Ubuntu setup (e.g. `/home`, `/var` or even `/media/data`). Before modifying or deleting any existing partition, **create a backup of your whole disk**.

Comment: Thanks for help, guys. I deleted the Grub partition, ran boot-repair just in case, and then I expanded the Ubuntu partition to the left, from a live session, as suggested -- after which I ran boot-repair again. It was pretty straightforward, actually.