# How to install kubuntu from Ubuntu and reserve all files in /home folder?

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, home-directory

I made 3 partitions

1----> swap partition (8gb)

2---->a 20 gb partition for ubuntu OS[/(root)]

3----> /home partition
(200gb approx.)

I have some anime and study stuff in home partition and want to switch to **kubuntu** 20.04 LTS preserving all the files in **/home**.

Is there a way to save all the files in home folder and switch to kubuntu . I don't want to save my other **Ubuntu** 20.04 LTS settings. How to do this in something else option in kubuntu installation?

Note-i am total **noob** in partition stuff but I made partition from some tutorial on youtube

Answer (score 1):

I circumvented that problem by creating a `/discworld` partition and putting my personal stuff in there.  During a reinstall I MOUNT and not format `/discworld`. 2 disks I use: a ssd for / and a hdd for `/discworld`.

My `/home` is void of anything personal and is part of `/` and not a separate partition.

You can use [How to create partition for data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862181/how-to-create-partition-for-data) as a reference and create your own partition (add a volume label!).

You then might need to shrink `/home`/ and enlarge this partition.
You can use [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) as a reference.

Then copy the directories in `/home/$USER/` over to this new partition and edit `~.config/user-dirs.dirs` to point to the new partition (keep a backup of this file on that partition so you can copy it back when you reinstall again) and if this all works remove the directories in `/home/$USER/`.

No more issues in the future: Use a live session for reinstalling and during the partition part remove / and /home and MOUNT your data partition (be careful here: pick the correct one; remember the volume label added when you created it).

After installation copy the backup of `user-dirs.dirs` to `~.config/user-dirs.dirs` and press F5 on the desktop to refresh.

extra: also ditch the swap partition. We nowadays use swapfile so we do not need to do anything for that anymore.

Comment: Thanks bro but I think I'm too dumb to understand this. What will happen if I formatted my 20gb OS Partition to install kubuntu and not format partition in which /home was set?

Comment: @SharadChandel naah. Be smart: make a BACKUP and you can always restore your data. My icon is from Elfenlied ;-) If you do that: it will work but you will have residual files from the old OS.

Comment: I missed that Masterpeice but will watch soon. What software to use for backup ? Thank you so much

Comment: for personal data? I would just copy it to an external disk.

Comment: I don't have any external disk lol! I just wanted to save my anime and study videos that I pirated . I don't want any configuration files.